# Problem with values on a foreach loop and how can I assign the correct value to the correct variable

Tags: php

I have a blog, and I am creating a script to show my posts (title-content-image) in another page. With the code below I get the first image of the post inside of `<div class="entry">`

The problem is : Imagine that I have 10 posts. Each of these has 1 title 1 content and images. Some of my posts do not have images at all. For example, the title of post 4 will be saved to variable "vartitles4", the content to "varcontents4" and the image to "varimages4". If post 4 does not have any images, it means that "varimages4" will have the value that was meant to be saved on "varimages5". (so varimages10 value will be null at the end)

So, how can I assign a value like a non-image.gif to varimages4 so that the script will work properly ?

Below is the code that gets the images. I have another two blocks of code like this one (title-content) before that.

```
$img = $xPathimages->query('//div[@class="entry"]//img'); 
$thefirst = 1;
$iimg=0;
foreach ($img as $imgs) { 
$images = $imgs->getAttribute('src'); 
${'varimages' . $iimg} = $images; //the value is saved to varimages1/2/3/4/5/6...
if($thefirst == 1) break; //gets only the first image
$iimg=$iimg+1;
}
```

Thank you people!

Comment: Each time I see variables variables I think: "oh come on, who arrays were invented for".

Comment: @awm $iimg is a counter, I forgot to add it.(updated)
@zerkms I am trying to have a result based on what I've learned by myself. So I choose the best method based on my knowledge.
@Kirby Todd Can you explain it to me better?

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You have a loop, and then you break out of it on the first iteration.  Why do you even have a loop?

Comment: @awm I think `item(0)` would be better.

Comment: @awm The code is working properly. The break is because as i wrote, I need to get only the first image of the post. A post may have more than one but I want only one.
@alex does item(0) works anywhere for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, wouldn't it just be:

```
$imgs = $xPathimages->query('//div[@class="entry"]//img');

$firstImage = $imgs[0];
```

I don't know the results of $xPathimages->query()...so maybe this is where "item(0)" would come into play.

```
$firstImage = $imgs->item(0);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I guess this is to get the first image of every post right?

Comment: @Mikey: Your xpath query selects a list of images out of divs that contain a class name of "entry".  It sounded like your requirement was to only select the first image.  This code should do that.